# Are <hr> and <br> inline or block elements?

Tags: html

My guess is that `<br>` might be inline and that `<hr>` might be block. But I don't really have a clue...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[`<hr>` is a block level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hr) whereas [`<br>` is an inline level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br).

Additional reference:

- [The HTML5 specification for `<hr>` by the W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-hr-element)
- [The HTML5 specification for `<br>` by the W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element)

Answer (score 6):

The `HR` element is defined to be element of [*block*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html#block). It’s also being displayed in its own line like any other [block element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3). Thus **`HR` is a block element**.

The `BR` element is defined to be element of [*special*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html#special) and that is defined to be [*inline*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html#special). It’s also not being displayed in its own like like a block element, but just creating a line break. Thus **`BR` is an inline element**.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [HTML 4.0 Strict DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd):

`<HR />` is a block-level element and `<BR />` is an inline element.

All the block-level elements are defined in the DTD thus:

```
<!ENTITY % block
     "P | %heading; | %list; | %preformatted; | DL | DIV | NOSCRIPT |
      BLOCKQUOTE | FORM | HR | TABLE | FIELDSET | ADDRESS">


<!ENTITY % heading "H1|H2|H3|H4|H5|H6">

<!ENTITY % list "UL | OL">

<!ENTITY % preformatted "PRE">
```

The rest are inline by default. Of course, a BR does force a line-break so acts similar to a block level element, but that doesn't mean it is.

Answer (score 1):

Years later...HR itself is a part of HTML5 but with more emphasis on it being a semantic and not layout element.  So keep using it but style it up with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

HR ELEMENT
Deprecated element: It is not advised to use and cannot bo used under the declaration of strict conformance.
Block element: There are vertical space before and after the element.
Empty element: There is only one tag:

---

. There is no end tag or text body contained by this element.

BR ELEMENT
Inline element: It is put where it needs to be, within the text body. Tehre is no vertical space before and after it.
Empty element.

Answer (score -2):

BR is an inline element, and has been deprecated in XHTML 2 in favor of LINE. (All academic at this point, of course...)

HR *was* a block element, but was deprecated in HTML 4.01 and is not part of the XHTML 1.0 Strict DTD.

Comment: -1 The current working draft of XHTML 2 has no `line` element, `HR` is not deprecated in HTML 4.01 and is also part of XHTML 1.0 Strict!

Comment: I stand corrected... that's what I get for double-checking something other than the actual DTDs.